# Ways to Upload File on multiple servers?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, file-upload

```
  Web.Config
  <add key="Location" value="C:/Upload" />

   //controller
   private readonly string _Location = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Location"];

   var fileName = Path.GetFileName(httpPostedFile.FileName);
   var path = Path.Combine(_Location, fileName);
   httpPostedFile.SaveAs(path);
```

This code is working fine locally. I realised that we have a load-balancer on the production env. I have 2 servers A,B behind the load-balancer. Is there a way to upload the file on both the servers A,B ? I tried to do some research and mostly developers suggested to upload the file on one of the server and then clone the Upload folder every 30 min or 1 hr.. But there should be a standard way of doing this through the code...(I have the server names and IP's)

Thnaks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not attempt to do this through your code.  What happens if one of the servers is down?  You would need to detect this, and then sync the file later when it came back up.

There are three sensible alternatives for this:

- Replication - Assuming you're using Windows, you can set up [Distributed File System](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753479%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) and have this handle getting the files between your servers.
- Synchronisation - Periodically synchronise files between your production servers.  This will have the problem that if you upload the file on A, it will not be immediately available on B.
- Shared Storage - The files are saved to a network share accessible by both servers.  In a load balanced environment, this may provide a single point of failure if the server providing the files is not available.

Answer (score 0):

The developers were right. Your application should not care about how many and which servers it runs on. Just talk to your system administrators and set up rsync or the likes to synchronize the directories, also to increase responsiveness as your application only has to save once.

If you *must*, however, it's as simple as:

```
foreach (string path in destinationPaths)
{
   httpPostedFile.SaveAs(path);
}
```

`SaveAs()` isn't guaranteed to be thread-safe, so you can't parallellize it. You could copy the stream and write it in parallel, but again, you don't want your code to be responsible for this.

Comment: wat should be the format of the path ? ipaddress/_Location + filename ?

Comment: What part of "you don't want this" don't you understand, especially if you don't know what UNC is?

Comment: I dont have a option right now to do it the clean way... things need to go to production before sat morning  (including qa process)..I have to handle it through code..